# Javasist throws javassist.CannotCompileException when instrumenting setString method of org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc, h2, javassist, javaagents

um trying to instrument jdbc methods while a server is running. I have tried it by instrumenting setString, setInt methods and executeQuery method while a simple mysql query is running as it is given in JDBC examples. It works totally fine when i instrument that setString method by injecting following line.

```
private void injectSetVariableMethods(CtMethod method) {
        if (isInEnum(method.getName().toUpperCase(), SetMethods.class)) {
            try {
                method.insertAt(1, true,
                        "javaagent.JDBCPublisher.fillArrayList(String.valueOf($2), " +
                        "Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName().toUpperCase());"
                );
            } catch (CannotCompileException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

But now, when i run it with the server which use h2, it gives the following exception.

```
javassist.CannotCompileException: by javassist.bytecode.BadBytecode: setString (ILjava/lang/String;)V in org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement: failed to resolve types
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertAt(CtBehavior.java:1210)
    at javaagent.JDBCTransformer.injectSetVariableMethods(JDBCClassTransformer.java:212)
    at javaagent.JDBCTransformer.transform(JDBCClassTransformer.java:99)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:638)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:234)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.ConnectionRollbackOnReturnInterceptor.invoke(ConnectionRollbackOnReturnInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState.invoke(ConnectionState.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.TrapException.invoke(TrapException.java:41)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:80)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:160)
    at org.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:429)
    at org.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:105)
    at org.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:230)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:96)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:109)
    at org.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:68)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: javassist.bytecode.BadBytecode: setString (ILjava/lang/String;)V in org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement: failed to resolve types
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:111)
    at javassist.bytecode.MethodInfo.rebuildStackMap(MethodInfo.java:423)
    at javassist.bytecode.MethodInfo.rebuildStackMapIf6(MethodInfo.java:405)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertAt(CtBehavior.java:1200)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: javassist.bytecode.BadBytecode: failed to resolve types
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:169)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:108)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException: org.h2.value.ValueNull
    at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:450)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.TypeData$TypeVar.fixTypes2(TypeData.java:345)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.TypeData$TypeVar.fixTypes(TypeData.java:330)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.TypeData$TypeVar.dfs(TypeData.java:274)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.fixTypes(MapMaker.java:394)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:167)
    ... 63 more
```

What i am doing with my fillArrayList method is, um passing those values into a ArrayList by checking the method name and adding '' for values set with setString. But it looks like it is instrumenting that method at somepoint, because i am getting the reimplemented queries with '?' replaced with respective values (strings with '' and ints as normal). But once the server has started it throws another set of exceptions which also involve h2.

```
    [2015-10-13 17:18:56,600] ERROR {org.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCLogsDAO} -  Failed to get logs. General error: "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1" [50000-140]
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1" [50000-140]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:156)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:279)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.toSQLException(DbException.java:252)
    at org.h2.message.TraceObject.logAndConvert(TraceObject.java:386)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:104)
    at org.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCLogsDAO.internalGetLogs(JDBCLogsDAO.java:427)
    at org.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCLogsDAO.getLogList(JDBCLogsDAO.java:317)
    at org.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.getLogs(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2332)
    at org.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.getLogs(CacheBackedRegistry.java:402)
    at org.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getLogsInternal(UserRegistry.java:1806)
    at org.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$3600(UserRegistry.java:60)
    at org.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$37.run(UserRegistry.java:1777)
    at org.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$37.run(UserRegistry.java:1774)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getLogs(UserRegistry.java:1774)
    at org.carbon.registry.indexing.ResourceSubmitter.submitResource(ResourceSubmitter.java:119)
    at org.carbon.registry.indexing.ResourceSubmitter.run(ResourceSubmitter.java:76)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at javaagent.JDBCPublisher.getArrayList(JDBCAgentPublisher.java:151)
    at javaagent.JDBCPublisher.modifyOriginalQuery(JDBCAgentPublisher.java:351)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:84)
    ... 19 more
[2015-10-13 17:18:56,601]  WARN {org.carbon.registry.indexing.ResourceSubmitter} -  An error occurred while submitting resources for indexing
org.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to get logs. General error: "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1" [50000-140]
    at org.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCLogsDAO.internalGetLogs(JDBCLogsDAO.java:465)
    at org.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCLogsDAO.getLogList(JDBCLogsDAO.java:317)
    at org.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.getLogs(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2332)
    at org.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.getLogs(CacheBackedRegistry.java:402)
    at org.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getLogsInternal(UserRegistry.java:1806)
    at org.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$3600(UserRegistry.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$37.run(UserRegistry.java:1777)
    at org.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$37.run(UserRegistry.java:1774)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getLogs(UserRegistry.java:1774)
    at org.carbon.registry.indexing.ResourceSubmitter.submitResource(ResourceSubmitter.java:119)
    at org.carbon.registry.indexing.ResourceSubmitter.run(ResourceSubmitter.java:76)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1" [50000-140]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:156)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:279)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.toSQLException(DbException.java:252)
    at org.h2.message.TraceObject.logAndConvert(TraceObject.java:386)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:104)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCLogsDAO.internalGetLogs(JDBCLogsDAO.java:427)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at javaagent.JDBCPublisher.getArrayList(JDBCAgentPublisher.java:151)
    at javaagent.JDBCPublisher.modifyOriginalQuery(JDBCAgentPublisher.java:351)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:84)
    ... 19 more
```

It throws bunch of IndexOutOfBoundExceptions repeatedly with a properly assigned sql query. What could have making this issue..... what should i do to correct this?

Comment: Based on the logs I would guess the array returned by `getStackTrace()` has less then two entries so you cannot retrieve a value from index `[1]`.

Comment: But what could be the reason for the cannotCompileException? I thought that something goes wrong at that point results in the last exception.

Comment: Could you please add more information about `javaagent.JDBCTransformer.injectSetVariableMethods(JDBCClassTransformer.java:212)` and the object you pass here `injectSetVariableMethods(CtMethod method)`.

Comment: Well the object passed there is the CtMethod it is going through at each iteration. Regarding the method, it just add a line to method. It will pass the given two values to fillArrayList method which will add those values to a arrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Find below a stripped down example, which prints the values of each invocation of the method `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.setString(int, String)`.

Following directory structure and content is assumed:

```
./instrumented/
h2-1.4.186.jar
javassist-3.7.ga.jar
SetStringDemo.java
```

execution of the example

```
javac -cp javassist-3.7.ga.jar;h2-1.4.186.jar SetStringDemo.java
java -cp .;instrumented/;javassist-3.7.ga.jar;h2-1.4.186.jar SetStringDemo
```

output

```
instrument class org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement
create test database and insert some rows         
idx: 2  value: 'name 0'                           
idx: 2  value: 'name 1'                           
idx: 2  value: 'name 2'                           
idx: 2  value: 'name 3'                           
idx: 2  value: 'name 4'
```

So the problem is most probably in the way you instrument the class.

Code used for the example.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;
import javassist.CtMethod;

public class SetStringDemo {

    // exception handling left out for the PoC
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if (Files.deleteIfExists(
                Paths.get("instrumented/org/h2/jdbc/JdbcPreparedStatement.class")
        )) {
            System.out.println("previously instrumented class removed");
        }

        System.out.println("instrument class org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement");
        ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        CtClass clazz = pool.get("org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement");
        CtMethod method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("setString");
        method.insertAt(1,
                "System.out.println(\"idx: \" + $1 + \"  value: '\" + $2 + \"'\");"
        );
        clazz.writeFile("instrumented/");

        System.out.println("create test database and insert some rows");
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:", "sa", "")) {
            String createTable = "CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE(ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(1024))";
            conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(createTable);

            String insertSql = "INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE VALUES(?, ?)";
            try (PreparedStatement insertStmnt = conn.prepareStatement(insertSql)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    insertStmnt.setInt(1, i);
                    insertStmnt.setString(2, "name " + i);
                    insertStmnt.executeUpdate();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but what is this instrumented folder?

Comment: @ransi It's used only for the PoC where the instrumented class is stored. 1) to keep the PoC as simple as possible, 2) to have the possiblity to check if the instrumentation was like expected. I assume you are using an agent to instrument your classes. Which doesn't matter for this PoC. But would have add unnecessary complexity.